# Upload audio file to server c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, audio, upload

How to upload audio file to server using HttpClient().
My audio file format is "testaudio.3gpp"
I want to do it using

```
await httpClient.PostAsync(uploadServiceBaseAddress, content);
```

Please suggest me the solution.
Full code below

```
string path = "sdcard/testaudio.3gpp";

                var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();



                var httpClient = new HttpClient();

                var uploadServiceBaseAddress = "https://example.com/UploadaudioFile.aspx";


                var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(uploadServiceBaseAddress, content);

                string resp = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

I think stream content or something have to add into content variable.

Comment: What's the code you have written so far and where you are stuck?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
string path = "sdcard/testaudio.3gpp";

                var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                var audioContent = new ByteArraycontent(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path));
                audioContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("audio/3gpp");
                content.Add(audioContent, "audio", "testaudio.3gpp");
                var httpClient = new HttpClient();

                var uploadServiceBaseAddress = "https://example.com/UploadaudioFile.aspx";


                var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(uploadServiceBaseAddress, content);

                string resp = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: I am working into xamarin cross platfrom app.System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes not found. namespace not found.

Comment: @ajoy Ahem, a tag on the question would have been helpful. Where does the audio come from? how do you want to get it? this was just a sample, and obviously you would have to write platform-specific code to get the data as byte[] or a `Stream` and then post that...